# Agile toolkit 4.2.1, crud not working, add, edit or delete forms not showing

Tags: atk4

I am new to agile toolkit so i will need help to start crud example working. I created model Customer with fields name, email and password. After that I created page that looks like this:

```
<?php
class page_account extends Page {
    function init() {
        parent::init();

        $this->add('CRUD')->setModel('Customer');
    }
}
```

When i load page in browser data from database is showing ok in table but when i click on add, edit or delete button nothing is happening. I looked at the tutorial at youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQYAeYS1RT8&index=2&list=PL7CBF92AB03A1CA3B.

If someone knows what is the problem please help.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer 4.2 branch, then please try latest 4.2.x version - 4.2.5.
You can get it here: https://github.com/atk4/atk4/tree/4.2

But if you're new to ATK4 framework, then you better start with 4.3 branch and don't look back :)
You can get it here: https://github.com/atk4/atk4
Book is here: http://book.agiletoolkit.org/